# Facebook Album Photo URL

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

How can I download facebook album photos from my app for a particular user. How can I access particular album photo URLs to download.

Comment: This link For ios ...but you helped my ans... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234